# Error: " Command line option --allow-releaseinfo-change is not understood in combination with the other options "

Tags: whonix

Error: " Command line option --allow-releaseinfo-change is not understood in combination with the other options "

This Error Message does not disappear, whatever the User does. I did nothing to my Whonix, it just updates itself into a deprecated repository, -- and NO move can get away this error, of above --

which happens on the Workstation.

On the Gateway, there's another problem with a hidden autostart of some "kdesudo" instance, - nowhere documented, not away-doable, just a small error popup, merely in the Gateway.

But the Repository and error Message when trying, to update the repository, is worse, and not overcomeable by a normal User.

While for some Users, this error goes away, for some other Users, it doesn't.

Result: I can't update my Whonix-Installation. Plain and simple. I suggest a tad more reality-nearness to the Whonix-Team, which for example does this website here way too complicated. Oompf. The "politeness" online is appalling, and confusing and deceiving, even anywhere. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an old, outdated, deprecated version of Whonix. KDE something?

> hidden autostart of some "kdesudo" instance

Rather old issue which doesn't happen anymore in recent or updated versions.

https://forums.whonix.org/t/kdesudo-error-popup-window-sdwdate-gui/5642

This is auxiliary. Will be fixed when updates are applied or new version installed.

> allow-releaseinfo-change

https://forums.whonix.org/t/apt-get-error-e-repository-tor-https-cdn-aws-deb-debian-org-debian-security-buster-updates-inrelease-changed-its-suite-value-from-testing-to-stable/7704 applies?

> I suggest a tad more reality-nearness to the Whonix-Team

Knowledge / awareness isn't the limiting factor Resources are. Unfortunately not possible. Details elaborated here:

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Reporting_Bugs#Linux_User_Experience_versus_Commercial_Operating_Systems

Due the issue described in above link... Please also have a look at https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Reporting_Bugs

To provide support it's required to know the installed version number, which command was run and what the output of the command was.

Also due the issue described in above link, it is required to somewhat stay on top of important Whonix news as described here:

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Stay_Tuned

In short, the important news listed on https://forums.whonix.org/tags/important-news are infrequent and non-voluminous. These will keep users posted about issues such as 
https://forums.whonix.org/t/apt-get-error-e-repository-tor-https-cdn-aws-deb-debian-org-debian-security-buster-updates-inrelease-changed-its-suite-value-from-testing-to-stable/7704 and also notify when old versions are deprecated, when it's required to upgrade and how, and so forth.

This type of question is less suited for tor.stackexchange.com and more suitable for forums.whonix.org since Whonix specific.

Can be hard to know sometimes however https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Support gives hints on which question fits where best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Sir. I will re-download Whonix, to install it anew - I had the 64bit merely a year old Version. Your Post is very helpful, I will yet look up all the Links in it. "Re-installing" Whonix is no "problem", but can for some Users be a more than 2 hours hassle, to recreate all these cloned, differently purposed Virtualbox Whonix VMs again, - with each different Programs installed, but I'll just take notes, which Programs I got in the different VMs, and also, of course, dpkg can output the installed programs list conveniently. I appreciate Whonix ENORMOUSLY - I will even before reinstalling try, if I can repair it, which would be much less hassle for me. I am extremely thankful for your so careful Reply, and that gives me a good Mood too. Thanks so much. But, I do know Linux, quite a bit. As Whonix did these two errors (updating not possible, as repository not updateable, whole reinstallation needed thusly, and the other kdesudo error in the Gateway not removable) quite to itself, I don't see, how You can demand "Whonix-nearness" from a User. A User uses the product. But that's all. A good product doesn't destroy itself, and is easily usable, as software. Whonix IS great, but could self-destroy itself quite less, in the future. Period. But thanks as said TRULY a lot for your Info.

Yet, I'd be glad, if You'd point me toward the new correct actual Repositories, as your Link points to an "aws" word containing NEW Repository, which isn't yet as such in my Whonix, in Synaptic. Also, the Whonix Support Page says, One should post here, and attach the Tag "whonix". That Error with the kdesudo error message in the Gateway, You pointed me SO brilliantly perfectly to. I JUST need the indication of the newest Repositories of Whonix now, -- this isn't prioritarily easily seeably indicated on the Whonix Website, sadly, yet. All a User of previous (64bit) Whonix Versions namely has to do, is renew the Repositories, so a (painful) new Installation IS NOT needed, then, with the new Repos. I myself REALLY don't find, where these (new) Whonix-Repos are neatly listed. MEGA Thanks, dear Friend of Computing. I'll check back here in under a Week, but feel truly no stress. I thank Ya so much.

I was reading here:

https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Whonix_Stable_Release

, that actually, I merely need to replace the "stretch" term, in Synaptic's Repos, by the "buster" term - thusly, I didn't need this additional option with apt, but I could just do update and upgrade, by apt, which now works. What I simply didn't know, is, that the initial 64bit "stretch" Debian-Version, -Base, of Whonix, was updated to the "buster" codeword newer level of Debian.

What would be lovely, in the Future, would be, if that "Whonix Repository" Tool could actually automatically, when started, upgrade the Repository, so the User has to enter oneself nothing, and "gets" always then the newest Repository, without having to even think of whatever Debian-Version-Levels. I AM sure, in a max 2 years, this is so. At last, I say, I hope I don't mess up my Whonix (I test it merely in one VM) by just replacing my stretch-repos by buster-repos, merely concerning the Debian-Repos. I DO also wonder, WHY I don't NEED that additional option, to "allow" "explicitely" that new Repo -- all I can say is, I'm updating my Whonix now to Buster Version Level of Debian, and am SO thankful, that EVEN this OTHER "kdesudo" error of the Gateway IS documented. Yet, anyway, a clear Indication on the Whonix-Website, about what exact current Repos are used, would be needed, would serve the Fame of Whonix. :)

Also, my further question I had in mind just now, is now answered: I MERELY had to change all "stretch" words, to "buster", in Synaptic's Repos; THAT actually DOES give to the User that new "aws" word containing ACTUAL new Buster Repo, - as I just saw that clearly, me looking into the upgrade-process - I there merely had to indicate my local regional language keyboard layout; While upgrading, that new "aws" Repo IS used, actually, - it is accessed automatically, once the "buster" codeword is used, instead of the "stretch" codeword, for Repos. I think, all is fine. And of course, after sudo apt update, and sudo apt upgrade, I do sudo apt dist-upgrade. It's surely now gonna work fine. Wow. Thanks SO mega. Awesome! :) Truly Thanks. :)

While upgrading at first a Whonix Workstation from stretch to buster, I said "Y", thusly took the newest Choices, when apt asked me about the two Packages Anon_Sources_List and Anon_Base_Files. The Workstation after upgrade, dist-upgrade and autoremove, booted up fine; YET, I had SOME errors, which I saw, as apt installed the buster packages, which errors I could not go back to (the console's go-back memory is limited, small, of LxTerm), but then, one final "small" error went "hostname: non-recoverable failure in name resolution" - yet, the then after dist-upgrade up-booted Whonix Workstation runs here the Tor Browser fine, so thusly, I assume, there is no "major" error at all, as these around four errors ARE probably normal in Whonix, which doesn't use these few in errors resulting functions of Debian, I assume. Short sum up, me realising, that a change from stretch to buster repos must be, was key in enabling me, to not have to resort to reinstall the whole Whonix, but to update it. That's a huge relief.

The "fatal" errors there during apt upgrade were: " insserv: FATAL: service mountkernfs has to be enabled to use service networking / insserv: FATAL: service urandom has to be enabled to use service networking " -

I chose at another point there "don't touch keymap", and also "restart services" (of course), and chose "Y" to take the newest Version, at the Config File "/etc/machine-id";

Foremostly now, in the System Menu, there's in the Gateway a new Entry called "NYX", which IS itself the new "Arm", and the old shortcut to the old "Arm Controller" simply has to be replaced by this new "NYX" Controller, which IS already in the System Menu, really convenient. A simple look into the Directory, after the old Arm Controller Shortcut results in an error message, reveals, what is, contains the new "NYX" Link, that IS quite crucial. :)

THE REALLY ONLY thingo bothering me IS though, that I can't seem to know, how so set a fix Mouse Cursor Size, LOL, as the Mouse Cursor is either in cases reset to being the small black standard Cursor INSTEAD of my Cursor Theme, or is simply mostly too small, at minimal Size actually, every time when booting up a Workstation or Gateway. I NOWHERE found a Documentation of this: The mere Mouse Cursor ACTUAL Size, in which Config File. Yet I mention this here merely, to finally display, that that's my sole issue remaining. Thusly, Whonix ROCKS - I use it on a Sparky Linux Host OS, as in Sparky Linux, unlike in Linux Mint and Ubuntu, qt5ct (qt5settings) works, which paints Virtualbox's Control Window nicely in the own custom colors, instead of in the normal ugly white backgrounded standard theme. I use pglgui in the Host and in all VMs. Stacer is the best Linux Service Manager, course. I use dphys-swapfile, on the Sparky Linux Host OS, instead of a swap partition, is a great advantage. Yet btw, dphys-swapfile can't quite speed up copyjobs' speed, on Laptops, which got a slow USB2 Connection to external Harddisks, so for downloading, I will anyway build a cheap "Download-PC", with a low watt power-supply, purposed for Downloading, which PC then has SATA, and the same casing as my strong stationary PC's casing, so the Harddisk-exchange then is maximally easy. Yet, I use Whonix only for normal HTTP Downloads while normally surfing.

The new "buster" level Whonix is some even 10 percent FASTER, than the previous Versions. That enables it, to run even faster, also on an albeit strong, 16GB RAM Laptop. I used Whonix already in the old 32bit Version, since now surely two to three years. I would like to mention this.

Gosh, was I glad, that my Gateway wasn't "broken" after upgrade, but that merely the Arm Controller is now called "NYX" and has a new Shortcut. Whonix IS perfect, rocks. Thanks SO much, good Sir.

I of course do the "NYX" new Arm Link into the Autostarts, in the "Sessions and Startup" System Menu, whereas I simply copied the Link (Command Phrase), which menulibre, the Menu Editor (which one should install), displays for the "NYX" Link, that, I copied into the command entry in the newly by me done Autostart of the NYX Console, so it starts up, when the Gateway boots.